# Не удаётся воспользоваться функциями Джинджер. Не подключается CSS файл

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую решить не смог. Смотрел схожие посты с моей проблемой - и проблема не решена.
Учу python по курсу ItProger.
Официальную документацию смотрел: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Ссылка на сам урок:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYeqcxaYUbQ

Файлик "urls.py":

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Файлик settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(pqqogq=1m=h&-g22c1n'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'itproger.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'itproger.wsgi.application'

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Ниже скрины основной директории и скрин местонахождения css файла.

[image: Скрин основной директории]

[image: Скрин сss файла]

**и код самой html странички:**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/main/css/main.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что css файл не подключается. А бутстрап подключается. При запуске сервера командой  python manage.py runserver
Сайт работает исправно. Стили бутстрапа задействованы. А стили, подключаемые из main.css - не работают. Там всего одна строка: body{background: red;}
Более того, при открытии странички - сервер в консоли выдаёт мне ошибку:
[14/Aug/2022 00:59:00] "GET /static/main/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1911
Которая означает, что он не видит, что файл находится по этому адресу. и в браузере при открытии странички тоже та же ошибка. Не удалось подключить файл css.
Браузер пишет: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.css

Где я ошибаюсь? Подскажите как исправить ошибку!

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось!
Добрый человек помог найти решение проблемы!
Я просто скопировал папку static в основную дирректорию рядом с приложением main и всё заработало!
`Дело всё в том, что я указал дирректорией основную папку. И сказал, что в ней нужно искать static.`